# Airflow Scheduler needs to be manually started each day

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am very new to Apache Airflow. I have airflow installed on a Google Cloud VM. I have two pipelines running that get data from API's and store them to BigQuery.
The issue that I am facing is that the airflow scheduler is not running automatically. I have to manually run it each day using "airflow scheduler" command. The next day, when I open Airflow I see the message "The scheduler does not appear to be running". Then I have to manually run te command again to start the scheduler.
I am using the SequentialExecuter. Does this have anything to do with it.

Has anyone else faced this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be because you are running the `scheduler` command/process in `fg` and closing the session.

Try running the scheduler as a daemon process with this command.

```sh
airflow scheduler -D
```

Comment: this worked.. the scheduler is running now, but now my DAGs are not running at the scheduled time. Do I have to change something?

Comment: It depends on many factors.. Did you enable the dag? Set `dags_are_paused_at_creation = False` in airflow.cfg file or activate it manually in the UI, if not activated already.

Comment: The DAGs are active.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to fix the issue.

1. I changed the database to postgreSQL and the executor to LocalExecutor.
2. I created two services: one for the airflow webserver and the other for the airflow scheduler. I ran the commands as the root user.

Below is the link from where I got help.
https://medium.com/@achilleus/easy-way-to-manage-your-airflow-setup-b7c030dd1cb8

Thanks everyone for sharing your answers.